# build legacy C code in eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I inherited a project written in C, running on Linux, with Cmake files written by the previous person. The previous person did not use IDE for this project, so I found it a bit hard to maintain this fairly large sized project, and I'm new to Cmake unfortunately :(.

I want to use eclipse (my OS is Linux) for this project to help me understand the project faster, and be able to build and debug it in Eclipse, so I do not have to run the build scripts manually every time. The project was in Mercurial, hence I check it out into my repository using Eclipse, then I have some options:

1. Open the project, and somehow make it into a C project which I can compile
2. Convert the code into makefile project, use Cross GCC toolchian, try to add all the pathes to 'include', then try to build (I'm on this path, but it seems Eclipse Juno needs me to find the path to include files myself, which is a lot to add manually T_T)
3. Create a new makefile project, import the code gradually as I go, I'm not super familiar with the code yet...
4. Some other ways...

Any suggestions please?

Also, in my case, which of the 3 options mentioned in http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial would be a good choice?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at emacs?

Comment: I do this by opening the cmake file in a text editor. The list of dependencies is fairly easy to spot. Then add the required source files to the eclipse project.

Comment: @Jay: Qt Creator supports CMake out of the box. No need to do anything, just open the project as `CMakeLists.txt` and start working on it. Creator determines everything automatically and does not even create extra files etc.

Comment: To Joe and Vlad, thanks for the suggestions of editors, but as I said, I'm using eclipse, and I'm trying to use an IDE, I do not need test editors, unless they can help me to compile and debug.

Comment: To Jay, thank you, that's what I'm doing now :), for this project thou, it's quite a lot of dependencies to add...and some path names are variables, which I'm still trying to find out what they are

Comment: Dependancies to add : `gcc -MM` but maybe your miracle editor has a solution for that, too.

Comment: Update on good progress, I was finally able to build the project in Eclipse, with errors, but that's OK, the point is I can click on the Build button, it did build. What I have done is go to project Properties, C/C++ Build, and instead of using default build command, type in Build command: "make -C ${ProjDirPath}/<where the CMakeLists.txt file is> VERBOSE=1 -j", in Settings, check Mach-O Parser

Comment: if you want to quickly understand the relationship between the files and the classes (or functions) I really suggest you run Doxygen on the project. You should also do what your predecessor didn't do, DOCUMENT and then code.

Comment: Thank you Oz123, Doxygen is great for documentation, I was looking for something like it, so thanks a lot! The only thing is that it looks like I have to spend quite sometime to configure it, and the comments in the project code was not so good, let's just say multiple people have touch it before. It's good now the project is in my hand, and I like doing things properly.